# How come some PyCharm script output does not get to screen readers

Tags: python, pycharm, accessibility

I'm trying to use PyCharm as the Python programming tool for beginning blind programmers.  It looks like a promising alternative for IDLE as PyCharm appears to provide better accessibility features.

In a simple interactive program below, when run under PyCharm, much, but not all, the output is **spoken** by my screen reader (NVDA).  When the same script is run directly under the cmd shell or power shell, **all** the output is **spoken**.  I abbreviated the original program as much as possible.  I added a sleep at the to see if the spoken output would appear, it did not help.

I fear the problem may be in the limbo between PyCharm and the screen savers, in my case NVDA.  But I hope it can be solved.

```
    # just_ask.py 12Aug2020 crs
"""
Demonstrate PyCharm / NVDA limitations with interactive script
"""
import time

inp = input("Enter Guess:")
print("From User:", inp)
print("We would like to hear this line")
ts = 5
print(f"Sleep {ts} seconds incase a pause would help")
time.sleep(ts)
print(f"After waiting")
```

Script Output:

```
Enter Guess:2
From User: 2
We would like to hear this line
Sleep 5 seconds incase a pause would help
After waiting
```

Spoken

```
ENTER GUESS: IS REPEATED AFTER 2 ENTERED ==> Enter Guess:2
NOT HEARD==> From User: 2
NOT HEARD==> We would like to hear this line
NOT HEARD - ONCE, AFTER MANY REPEATS, WE HEAR ==> Sleep 5 seconds incase a pause would help
NOT HEARD==> After waiting
```

All below is heard when run on "cmd>" shell:

```
C:\Users\raysm\Desktop\braille_2023E\my_work\20q>python just_ask.py
Enter Guess:2
From User: 2
We would like to hear this line
Sleep 5 seconds incase a pause would help
After waiting

C:\Users\raysm\Desktop\braille_2023E\my_work\20q>
```

Simpler program with just print() statements, looping with delay in case time is needed.  The following program gets no spoken output when run under PyCharm, but output is fine when run under cmd>.

```
import time
for n in range(1, 10+1):
    print("We would like to hear this line", n)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: At first glance, this looks like an issue with PyCharm. I recommend that you post it on their issue tracker. You can get their easily by clicking Help > Submit a Bug Report... in the main menu.

Comment: What happens if you change `print("From User:", inp)` to `print(f"From User: {inp}")`? Based on your other examples, I expect that this will be voiced. So for some reason it is voicing f-string output with `print()`, but not regular strings.

Comment: Changing to print(f"From User: {inp}") has no effect. Please see my edits to the original post.  I can't reliably repeat the reruns, but once in a while of numerous reruns the "Sleep 5 seconds..." line is spoken.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Well...It's simpler yet - we get no print output when run under PyCharm.  See my edit to original post.

Comment: We also get the same problem with the JAWS screen reader.